# sequence of continous function function converging uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

could anyone help me to solve the problem?

I know that $\sup\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|\}\to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m:= \max \{|f(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$

We have

$|f_n(x)|-|f(x)| \le |f_n(x)-f(x)|$, hence $|f_n(x)| \le |f_n(x)-f(x)|+c$.

To $\epsilon=1$ there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n>N$. Hence

$|f_n(x)| \le 1+c$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n>N$.

Let  $m_n:= \max \{|f_n(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$. Then

$M \le \max\{m_1,m_2,...,m_N, 1+c\}$